# openjpa2.0 migration flush behaviour of entity manager

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I am migrating my project from openjpa0.9.5 to openjpa2.0.

In one of the scenarios, i see a difference in the flush behaviour of entity manager. Below is the scenario.

```
Query aQuery = entitymanager.createquery(select e from employee e where e.id = 4);

Enployee e = (Employee)aQuery.getSingleResult();

e.setName("test");

entitymanager.flush();

System.out.println(e.getVersion());

// Where version column denotes the version of employee.
// Version field is annotated with @Version in the Employee entity
```

In openjpa0.9.5 - 1 is printed
In openjpa2.0.0 - 2 is printed

Is there any difference in flush behaviour?

Comment: what server do you use, can you post datasource ?

Comment: I am using oracle datasource which has a configured jpatransaction manager around it

Comment: could you post the code of the declaration, also what app server do you use

Comment: I am trying to test the above code by JUnit

Comment: From the code you posted and without datasource configuration I can only advise you to chekk for IgnoreChanges and FlushBeforeQueries properties

Comment: what is the version BEFORE setting "name"? Where you run it (JavaSE or JavaEE) is irrelevant to the question. I'm sure the openjpa log would tell you a lot ...

Comment: Version is 1 before setting name

Comment: Version is 1 before setting name

Comment: Are there any updates on this thread from anyone